# How can I get the ID of an icon of another application?

Tags: android

I need to create home shortcuts of other applications. in order to do that I need to get the ID of the icon drawable.

I can get the actual drawable, but i dont know how to get the ID of it without knowing the name of the drawabale.

Is there a way to find the name of the drawable or get the ID from the drawable object?

i think i said drawable too many times.

```
//get icon drwable
public Drawable getIcon(String pack) {
        final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            return pm.getApplicationIcon(pack);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

public void makeShortcut(String pack){
         Intent shortcutIntent;

            shortcutIntent = new Intent();
            shortcutIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(pack, ".classname"));
            int iconId =geIconId(pack); // a default icon for now TODO


            Log.i("icon id", ""+iconId);
            shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            final Intent putShortCutIntent = new Intent();
            putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,
                    shortcutIntent);

            // Sets the custom shortcut's title
            putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,  getAppName(pack));
            putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(
                    context,iconId));
            putShortCutIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            context.sendBroadcast(putShortCutIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to know the id of the drawable?

Comment: because this method needs an ID ` putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context,iconId));`

Answer (score 1):

Icon launcher drawableId is same. I think, first get application icon, then start that application  by settingcomponent.

[image]

You can get the Drawable icon of an app by using:

```
Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.example");
```

Then

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
startActivity(intent);

Comment: processName which you want to take icon. or just use                    Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.xxx.xxx");

Comment: the problem is I already got the drawble. i need the ID from the drawble. in order to get the id, i need to know the name of the drawble

Comment: Do you want to start an applicaiton from your application ?

Comment: I looked different apps launcher icon id's all of them are same.

Answer (score 0):

ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(pkgContext, iconId) do the trick!    [create shortcut for thrid-party app, is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339231/create-shortcut-for-thrid-party-app-is-that-possible/17561676#17561676)